# How do I get the minimum value of a node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

There is a range of values coming out of the length node as shown below, and I want to capture the minimum value out of all of them.

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you!

[image: Multiple value coming out of length node]

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, it is by using the [attribute statistic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_statistic.html) node.

Comment: Yes. The math 'Minimum' node returns the the minimum of the 2 inputs.